# In Kotlin how do I groupBy type

Tags: kotlin

I would like to group a list by the subtypes of its generic type argument.

That is a have a list with three types of objects all are a subtype of some type A.

The closest I can get is `it.javaClass.typeName` or `it.javaClass.kotlin`

The former creates keys of Strings which isn't ideal, but I can deal with.  The later creates keys of `KClassImpl` which I can't actually import let alone create an instance of.

How do you groupBy type, then access the different keys in the resulting map?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can refer to kotlin class instances as Foo::class

```
data class Person(
    val firstName : String,
    val lastName : String
)

data class City(
    val name : String,
    val population: Int
)


fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val list = listOf(
        Person("John", "Doe"),
        Person("Eugene", "Cuckoo"),
        City("London", 8500000),
        City("Berlin", 3500000),
        City("Hötyökmáró", 2)
    )

    val grouped = list.groupBy { it.javaClass.kotlin }

    println("Persons: ${grouped[Person::class]}")
    println("Cities: ${grouped[City::class]}")

}
```

Comment: While this works, and I am happy to tick the tick, but then I get a deprecation warning: 'get(Any?): V? is deprecated. Use 'getRaw' instead.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: Yes, always. It's not happy because there's a type mismatch, albeit a subtle one that Java would allow. Kotlin allows it temporarily but soon won't. Sometimes it helps to use the "Specify type explicitly" intention and the show type of expression feature to see what the issue is. Here, it can be fixed by changing "val grouped" to be:

`val grouped: Map<KClass<*>, List<Any>> = list.groupBy { it.javaClass.kotlin }`

Comment: @Gavin I think that deprecated warning has gone away, it was temporary to make people aware of type safety between `get` and `getRaw` before a change as made to make `get` typed.

Comment: Indeed the deprivation warning has gone away, and in fact `getRaw` is no longer recognised, though IntelliJ is replacing `data.get(Type::class)` with `data[Type::class]`